# How can I prove that the n-dimensional hyper-rectangle is closed?

Tags: analysis

How can I prove that the n-dimensional hyper-rectangle

$S=I_1\times I_2\times \cdot\cdot\cdot  \times I_n$
 is a closed set in $\Bbb R^n$?

My attempt:

Let $x=(x_1, x_2,  \cdot\cdot\cdot, x_n)  \in S' $.

To prove that S is a closed set, we will show that S contains all its limit points.

To show this, it suffices to show that $x_j \in I_j$ for $j=1,2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,n$

We will prove the case of $j=1$. Then we can imitate the process for the other cases.

Since $x_1$ is a limit point of $I_1$, $N'(x_1;\varepsilon)\cap I_1 \neq \emptyset$ for all $\varepsilon >0$

It follows that $[N(x_1;\varepsilon)\cap I_1] \times \underbrace{\Bbb R \times \cdots \times \Bbb R }_{\text{n-1 times}}  \neq \emptyset$.

I AM STUCK HERE

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to prove this using that $I_1$ is closed or don't you want to use this knowledge?

Comment: In the former case, since the open neighbourhoods of $x_1$ in $\mathbb{R}$ are exactly of the form $(x_1-\epsilon, x_1+\epsilon)$ you get $x_1 \in I_1$

Comment: @ Valentin Could you please give me a detailed explanation? Since $x_1$ is a limit point of $I_1$, we obtain $N(x_1;\varepsilon) \cap I_1 / \{x_1\}$. How come you guarantee $x_1 \in I_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course we have to assume that the given intervals $I_k\subset{\mathbb R}$ $(1\leq k\leq n)$ are closed. Consider an arbitrary point $\xi=(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)\in \bar S$. We have to prove that necessarily $\xi\in S$.

Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. As $\xi\in\bar S$ there is an $x\in S$ with $|\xi-x|<\epsilon$. Looking at the first coordinates we can say that
$|\xi_1-x_1|\leq|\xi-x|<\epsilon$. This implies that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $x_1\in I_1$ with $|\xi_1-x_1|<\epsilon$. If $\xi_1$ were outside of (i.e., at a positive distance from)  $I_1$ the latter could not hold. It follows that in fact $\xi_1\in I_1$, and similarly $\xi_k\in I_k$ for all $k$. But this means that $\xi\in S$.